# Unset and set a new value to a property defined with defineProperty

Tags: javascript, properties, defineproperty

I define an object property with `Object.defineProperty`. But then how can I unset it?

I tried to unset it with `delete foo.bar` (where `bar` is the property), but it seems it doesn't work:

```
var foo = {};
Object.defineProperty(foo, "bar", {
    get: function () {
        console.log("first call");
        delete foo.bar;
        var value = 3;
        foo.bar = value;               
        return value;            
    }
  , writeable: true
  , enumerable: true
});
console.log(foo.bar);
console.log(foo.bar);
```

Output is:

```
first call
3
first call
3
```

I expected the following output:

```
first call
3
3
```

The idea is that after the first `get` I want to replace the property with a value.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing the `configurable` option to `defineProperty` function, fixes the issue:

```
var foo = {};
Object.defineProperty(foo, "bar", {
    get: function () {
        console.log("first call");
        delete foo.bar;
        var value = 3;
        foo.bar = value;
        return value;
    }
  , writeable: true
  , enumerable: true
  , configurable: true
});
console.log(foo.bar);
console.log(foo.bar);
```

Output:

```
first call
3
3
```

From [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

> `configurable`
>
> `true` if and only if the type of this property descriptor **may be changed and if the property may be deleted** from the corresponding object.
>
> Defaults to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set configurable property to allow delete `configurable: true`
But as best practice, do not mix up data property and accessor property